# What's the difference between "flagging → duplicate" and "flagging → should be closed → duplicate of..."?

Tags: support, flagging

I remember this confusion that I had before I was given the close-vote priviledge. Since I can't show it on this site, let me use BioSE's flagging (where I don't have close vote):

[image]

and

[image]

Apart from them being in two different locations, what do the two different duplicate buttons do? Is there a difference between *flagging as a duplicate* and *flagging to close as a duplicate* that I'm not aware of? Or was it possibly just a redundant mistake on SE's part? Or possibly kept in both columns just for a sense of completeness?

Comment: You can get to this via flag button on this site too.  I noticed duplicate of duplicate too, but I couldn't flag it :D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no difference between the two options.

(See [New flagging dialog has a duplicate for duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196583/new-flagging-dialog-has-a-duplicate-for-duplicate) on Meta Stack Exchange)

Comment: :O FGITW! You win this round, baby seal, but I will have my revenge . . .

Comment: @M.A.R. I actually posted an even shorter answer even faster, but it got [auto-converted to a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98950/312770). Well, benefits of being a mod, you get notified about meta posts...